# Is my data secure after factory reset with NO password SET

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery, encryption

I had one plus 8 pro brand new phone Android 10. I sold the phone in a week's time. I never set any password or screen lock. I understand android 10 uses file-based encryption. I just did a factory reset and sold the phone. can the buyer retrieve by data though I have not set the screen password? will the file-based encryption take care?

Answer (score 1):

The file encryption on Android 10 is used no matter if you have set a lock screen password or not. The file encryption does incorporate the password but an additional secret random key is also required for accessing encrypted files.

This key is erased on factory reset, so encrypted files become impossible to decrypt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Makes sense. That means my data is completely erased. And and the buyer can never retrieve. The buyer is a local mobile shop who works on software.

Comment: Just for clarity, the factory reset deletes all the user files, correct? (Yes, some of their bytes could remain on non-volatile storage regardless, but in this case, encrypted.)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket AFIK the user data partition is simply reformatted and the all encryption keys are erased and new keys are generated. This mostly all user data will remain but as the encryption keys are gone it can not be recovered.

Comment: I just heard from oneplus the phone manufacturer that encryption works only when the screen password is set. Please help

Comment: Do the controllers for the non-volatile storage chips in most Android devices perform TRIM-like functions as with SSDs?  Also, do they do anything like *"Read zero after TRIM"*?  If so, data recovery would likely require special equipment.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1749575/why-is-this-data-seemingly-gone

Comment: @Dave That is a very old info. Before Android 6 or 7 this was true.

Comment: @Robert Can you help me with any article on oneplus 8 pro where I confirm the phone is encrypted and uses file-based encryption? Also, I need to understand if they use 128-bit or 256-bit encryption. Sorry, I know I am asking too much. I just to know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @Dave The only way to confirm encryption is to verify the encryption by performing the decryption manually. So you would need a rooted device. The most problematic part is how to extract the master encryption key for user and non-user data (those files that are accessible before first user logon). With root permissions you may be able to extract some intermediate keys from one of the processes memory. This is also the only way to verify AES256 is used because from encrypted data you can not tell this. But I am not an Linux encrypted file-system expert. So I can't help you on that topic.